# How get values from the multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like below. I want to get the value of startTime and endTime. The values for the startTime and endTime should come in the dropdown. Means the value of startTime and endTime for the 1st array block should come in one option of the select box and the 2nd array block should come in the 2nd option. I have around 100+ array block for this.

```
Array
(
    [upcoming] => Array
        (
            [webinars] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [times] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [startTime] => 2015-03-23T11:00:00Z
                                            [endTime] => 2015-03-23T12:00:00Z
                                        )

                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [times] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [startTime] => 2015-03-26T11:00:00Z
                                            [endTime] => 2015-03-26T12:00:00Z
                                        )

                                )

                        )
)

            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

So for getting the values from the array I have made my code like this

```
foreach($webinars as $key=>$val) {
    foreach($val as $test) {
      foreach($test as $ksh) {
        foreach($ksh['times'] as $k=>$v) {
          echo $v['startTime'];
          echo $v['endTime'];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But I don't think getting startTime and endTime by using 4 foreach is a smarterway. I want to know is there any smarter way of getting those values? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Is the `times` array always going to contain one single array element only, or can it be more than that? And same for the `upcoming` key, can there be different ones on that level as well?

Comment: @CBroe yes the times and upcoming will have the one single array element always.

Comment: Well then you shouldn’t need to loop through those levels, but can access the elements by their key directly.

Comment: @CBore can you share some code?

Comment: what is your php version?

Answer (score 3):

> the times and upcoming will have the one single array element always

Well then the actual `webinars` level is the only thing that can have multiple entries, so something simple such as

```
foreach($webinars['upcoming']['webinars'] as $webinar) {
  echo $webinar['times'][0]['startTime'] . ' - ' . $webinar['times'][0]['endTime'] . "<br>\n";
}
```

should do … (Assuming your variable that holds this whole array is named `$webinars`.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, or solve your problem, but maybe you can get an idea how to solve what you want in different way:

```
<?php
    $arr = array
    (
     'upcoming' => array
     (
      'webinars' => array
      (
       0 => array
       (
        'times' => array
        (
         0 => array
         (
          'startTime' => '2015-03-23T11:00:00Z',
          'endTime' => '2015-03-23T12:00:00Z'
          )

         )
        ),

       1 => array
       (
        'times' => array
        (
         0 => array
         (
          'startTime' => '2015-03-26T11:00:00Z',
          'endTime' => '2015-03-26T12:00:00Z'
          )

         )

        ),
       ),

      'status' => 1
      )

     );
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($arr);
    echo "</pre>";


    function searchByKey(array $array, $search,&$result) {
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $key => $value) {
            if ($search === $key)
                $result[] = $value;
        }
        return false;
    }

    $startTimeArray = array();

    searchByKey($arr, 'startTime', $startTimeArray);

    var_dump($startTimeArray);

    $endTimeArray = array();

    searchByKey($arr, 'endTime', $endTimeArray);

    var_dump($endTimeArray);



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need array_map(), read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Try this:

```
$array = array ( 'upcoming' => array ( 'webinars' => array ( 0 => array ( 'times' => array ( 0 => array ( 'startTime' => '2015-03-23T11:00:00Z', 'endTime' => '2015-03-23T12:00:00Z', ), ), ), 1 => array ( 'times' => array ( 0 => array ( 'startTime' => '2015-03-26T11:00:00Z', 'endTime' => '2015-03-26T12:00:00Z', ), ), ), ), 'status' => '1', ), );

$start = array_map(function($n) {return $n['times'][0]['startTime'];}, $array['upcoming']['webinars']);

print_r($start);
echo "<br>";
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-03-23T11:00:00Z
    [1] => 2015-03-26T11:00:00Z
)
*/

echo implode("<br>", $start);

/*
2015-03-23T11:00:00Z
2015-03-26T11:00:00Z
*/

$end = array_map(function($n) {return $n['times'][0]['endTime'];}, $array['upcoming']['webinars']);

echo "<br>";
print_r($end);    
echo "<br>";
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-03-23T12:00:00Z
    [1] => 2015-03-26T12:00:00Z
)
*/

echo implode("<br>", $end);
/*
2015-03-23T12:00:00Z
2015-03-26T12:00:00Z
*/
```

Comment: @NewUser you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might help you:

```
<?php

    $array['upcoming']['webinars']=array(
            0 => array(
                    'times' => array(
                                0 => array(
                                        'startTime' => '2015-03-23T11:00:00Z',
                                        'endTime' => '2015-03-23T12:00:00Z',
                                    )
                        )

                ),
            1 => array(
                    'times' => array(
                                0 => array(
                                        'startTime' => '2015-03-26T11:00:00Z',
                                        'endTime' => '2015-03-26T12:00:00Z',
                                    )
                        )

                ),
        );


    ?>

    <select name="time_select">
    <option value = ''> Select Time </option>
    <?php

        $webinars = $array['upcoming']['webinars'];
        foreach($webinars as $key => $val) {
            foreach($val['times'] as $time) {
                echo '<option value="any_value">'.$time['startTime'].'-----'.$time['endTime'].'</option>';    
            }
      }
    ?>
    </select>
```